# Spring MVC forwarding HTTP POST request as a HTTP GET to another controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I am trying to get my controller to forward a POST request to another controller with some parameters:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegisterController {
    //...
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processSubmit(@Valid Voter voter, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {
          //...
          request.setAttribute("firstName", voter.getFirstName());
          request.setAttribute("lastName", voter.getLastName());
          request.setAttribute("ssn", voter.getSsn());
          logger.info("VoterID exists, returning redirect:/question/prepare");
          return "forward:/question/get";
        }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/question")
public class QuestionController {
    //...
    @RequestMapping(value="/get", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String prepareVoterBean(@RequestParam String firstName, 
            @RequestParam String lastName, @RequestParam String ssn, Model model) {
        logger.info("QuestionController got GET REQUEST for " + firstName + lastName + ssn);
        VoterBean bean = new VoterBean();
        bean.setFirstName(firstName);
        bean.setLastName(lastName);
        bean.setSsn(ssn);
        model.addAttribute("questions",bean);
        return "questionPage";
    }
}
```

I am trying to code QuestionController to create a new model with the parameters that I received from processSubmit(). The problem is when I return:/question/get from processSubmit, the request is forwarded as a HTTP POST request, and the server is returning a HTTP Status 405 - "Request method 'POST' not supported. In order to build a new model within QuestionController, I think I need to forward a HTTP GET request from processSubmit().

I did some research on Spring Web MVC framework documentation, and read that redirect prefix can be used to forward a request as GET request from POST method, but when I tried redirect prefix (i.e. `return redirect:/question/get`), the server returns HTTP 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the 400 error, the `redirect` attempts to send a GET request to your other controller method, but that method requires the different `RequestParam`s which your new request might not have and thus fails.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't do that.

Factor out the common part between both controller methods in a helper method, and call this helper method from both controller methods.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `the uri of /question/get requires params(firstName, lastName, ssn)`, 
but when redirecting to it, you give nothing to it. 
maybe help you:)